# Setting a pointer to a new buffer of length n

Tags: c++

I am trying to recreate a dumbed-down version of the STL string class. I am trying to implement a constructor that will take a c-string as an argument.

```
inline String::String(const char* s)
{
    buffer = get_new_buffer(s);
    size = strlen(s);
}
```

To set the pointer, I wrote a function, `get_new_buffer(char* n)` const to reallocate a new buffer for the string and to set a pointer to the new buffer.

```
inline char* String::get_new_buffer(char* n) const
{
    return (strlen(n) == 0 ? nullptr : new char* [strlen(n)]());
}
```

I am having an issue with the `get_new_buffer` function return. It is telling me that the return type doesn't match the function type, but why would that be? In my return statement, why is it not returning a pointer to the new buffer, and what is mine set to return?

Comment: What is the type of `buffer`? Also the new buffer function should return `new char[strlen(n)]` otherwise there's an extra level of pointer there

Comment: You want `new char [strlen(n)]());`. Otherwise you mean an array of `char*` pointers.

Comment: There are two difficult problems in computer science, naming, cache invalidation and off-by-one error, my guess is that your having problem with the last. How much place do you need to store a string?

Comment: And watch your `const`s.

Comment: Do NOT forget the terminating null. The whole universe will crash down around the program... OK. That's a bit dramatic. Dial it back, man.  `strlen` and all of the low-level string utilities count on the terminating null character being in place. If you forget to make space for it or forget to add it, the program [will be unreliable in oft-mysterious ways.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm pretty sure that you didn't mean to add parentheses after the end of `new char [strlen(n)]`.

Comment: @jjramsey Probably not, you're right. Just blindly copied ;-)

Comment: @jjramsey there is nothing wrong with putting `()` after `new char[]`, at least in C++11 and later, that will simply value-initialize the allocated `char`s to `'\0'`.

Comment: ^^^^ all but one of which being about to be overwritten anyway (assuming the +1 is added to the offending code). E.g. an expensive way to set a terminating nullchar.

Comment: @WhozCraig And since the array is of length `strlen(n)`, not `strlen(n)+1`, there wouldn't even be a null terminator, anyway.

Comment: @jjramsey thus the *"assuming the +1 is added to the offending code"* part of that comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with this code:

- `get_new_buffer()` is declared to return a `char*` pointer, but is allocating a `char*[]` array, which decays to a `char**` pointer.  That is the mismatch the compiler is complaining about.  Drop the extra `*` on the array's element type.  You want an array of `char`s, not an array of pointers to `char`.
- the code is not copying the `char` elements of the input `s` string into the allocated `buffer`.
- the code is not checking if `s` is `nullptr`.  Calling `strlen()` with a `nullptr` input is *undefined behavior*.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
inline String::String(const char* s)
{
    buffer = get_new_buffer(s, size);
}

inline char* String::get_new_buffer(const char* n, size_t &size) const
{
    char *buffer;
    size_t bufsize = (n != nullptr) ? strlen(n) : 0;
    if (bufsize > 0) {
        buffer = new char[bufsize + 1];
        strcpy(buffer, n);
    }
    else
        buffer = nullptr;
    size = bufsize;
    return buffer;
}
```